# Install ubuntu overwriting an old Windows8 trial partition

Tags: dual-boot, windows-8, system-installation

On my desktop I have two partition containing both windows8, one of them is an expired trial. I'm a windows based developer and I want to learn even some Linux development stuff, so I want to install Ubuntu and overwrite that expired Window 8 version. At present when my computer boot there is  a dual boot that let me to choose from which win8 start. Can I use the same dual boot to choose between windows and ubuntu? Do I have to remove that dual boot ( don't know how, but will investigate ) before installing Ubuntu? Can I reuse the already present boot manager and must overwrite the useless partition with Ubuntu?

Comment: Ubuntu uses grub wich stands for GRand Unified Bootloader, you might want to add more details as if your computer uses UEFI or not for people be able to help you. I personally have no experience with it or either dualboot.

Comment: How can check to see about UEFI? so basically you say is better to have a single boot machine and the install ubuntu using Grub as a dual boot manager?

Comment: Ubuntu will instal grub and for UEFI https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UEFI http://askubuntu.com/questions/221835/installing-ubuntu-on-a-pre-installed-windows-8-64-bit-system-uefi-supported

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Personally, i whould remove the expired windows partition and use wubi from the good one to install ubuntu, this way you won't have to worry about grub or annything you dont have the old windows and you whould even be able to delete ubuntu from the software manager in the working windows !

http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/windows-installer

Comment: "Have a new PC with the Windows 8 logo or using UEFI firmware?"

Comment: It is an old 32 bit pc with vista in the past

Comment: WUBI is not officially supported anymore and WILL break!

Comment: With Wubi, our officially supported Ubuntu installer for Windows, you can install and uninstall Ubuntu easily and safely. For 12.04 LTS only.

Comment: @alexander255 it worked actally.

Comment: @FelicePollano WUBI will install Ubuntu inside of Windows, and may have a performance impact that will degrade your Ubuntu experience. I would remove the partition where Windows is installed and install Ubuntu in the empty space instead.